# Android - metadata folder on svn

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to commit my project on SVN , but i have a question about Eclips metadata folder , Do I need to ignore **.metadata** folder from svn repository ?
I ignored Gen & Bin folder , but i don't know about .metadata folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Ignore it. It was auto generated by Eclipse. When you create a new workspace using eclipse you can find .metadata inside the newly created folder.